# CakePHP 3 routing dynamic url

Tags: url, cakephp, dynamic, routes

I have an eCommerce website and need to create some custom URLs. These URLs will be generated dynamically. The structure will be

Example URL: http://website.com/categoryname/product-title

Here the category name is dynamic. It will change for each product, it can be

website.com/buttons/CP1 or
website.com/ribbons/red so on

In any case these URLs should be redirected to http://website.com/products/productdetail/product-title

I tried the following script:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:type/:slug/*',
    ['controller' => 'Products','action' => 'productDetail'],    
    ['type' => '\b(?:(?!admin)\w)+\b'],
    [
        'slug' => '[A-Za-z-]+',
        'pass' => [
            'slug'
        ]
    ]
);
```

`['type' => '\b(?:(?!admin)\w)+\b']` is to exclude the other controllers. In this case 'Admin'. This works but the parameters passed through the URL (product-title) is not getting in the controller function(productDetail)

Any help will be appreciated.

It is fixed. Updated script below.

```
$routes->connect(
'/:type/:slug/*',
['controller' => 'Products','action' => 'productDetail'], 
[
    'type' => '\b(?:(?!admin)\w)+\b',  
    'pass' => ['slug']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API the `connect()` function only accepts 3 parameters and you are actually passing 4. See [Cake Routing Router -  Connect](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_connect)

I have not tested this at all, but I think you should re-write it like this:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:type/:slug/*',
    ['controller' => 'Products','action' => 'productDetail'], 
    [
        'type' => '\b(?:(?!admin)\w)+\b', 
        'slug' => '[A-Za-z-]+',   
        'pass' => ['slug']
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I tried this script I am getting 'ButtonController' could not found exception.  Link is http://localhost/sewcool/buttons/test-123658

Comment: Its fixed. I removed the 'slug' key from the last parameter. Updated my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out!